# Question on polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

My book states that the polynomials over a field $\mathbb{R}$ mod $(x^2+1)$ form a commutative ring with addition and multiplication. Why is this? I don't understand how there is closure under multiplication.

Comment: Do you mean the ring $R[x]/(x^2 + 1)$ as a [factor ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_ring) of $R[x]$ by the ideal $(x^2 + 1)$? Why shouldn't it be closed under multiplication?

Comment: @K.Stm. I'm not sure I haven't seen factor rings yet. I think it's not closed under multiplication because all elements in the set are of degree $\leq$ 1. When you multiply two monomials, there is no closure.

Comment: @xcrypt: But *modulo $x^2+1$*, a polynomial of higher degree is *equal* to a polynomial of degree $\leq 1$.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: For rings, one normally uses *commutative* instead of *abelian*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Modulo $x^2+1$*, a polynomial of higher degree is *equal* to a polynomial of degree $\leq 1$.

For example,
$$\begin{align}x^2+12x+35=(x^2+1)+12x+34\;&\equiv\; 12x+34\bmod (x^2+1)\\
x^3+2x-3=x(x^2+1)+x-3\;&\equiv\; x-3\bmod (x^2+1)\end{align}$$